# not call viewWillAppear while popping from view controller in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, viewwillappear

I am using iOS image gallery for selecting the image in my code
When I have done selecting image it calls the viewWillAppear method of my current class in which I have clear some variable.
So it clear the variable again which I not want.
 Is there any method when the image gallery close it not calls the viewWillAppear method.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is your architecture and not the way the `UIView` cycle works. Your question is a bit vague, so I don't fully understand the complexity of your application and so I can't provide a suitable solution to fix your problem.

Although for a quick fix, you can do something like this:

1) When you open your gallery, just set a BOOL to YES.

2) When you close your gallery and you enter in `viewWillAppear`, just check if the BOOL is YES, if YES, then do not clear your variables.

3) Don't forget to reset your BOOL value again to NO.

Answer (score 2):

Simply no.

When you present the `UIImagePickerController`, it fill the full screen. And when it dissmis, the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` will be called.

You can try to move the variables that you'd like to keep in `viewDidLoad` method, if it is possible.